# Accessing a function inside another file in Loopback4

Tags: testing, import, require, loopback4

```
 it("Provides Station Details", () => {
        
    const result = compareIssueDate('2021-03-01', '2020-03-09');
    console.log('Result: ', result)
    expect(result).to.have.status(200);
    console.log('Tested successfully..!!!')
   });
```

---

```
export function compareIssueDate(a: any, b: any) {

  const bandA = a.mlIssueDt;
  const bandB = b.mlIssueDt;

  let comparison = 0;
  if (bandA > bandB) {
    comparison = -1;
  } else if (bandA < bandB) {
    comparison = 1;
  }
  return comparison;
}
```

Path of **compareIssueDate** is as: **getting-started/src/controllers/hello.controller.ts**

Path of **app.test.js** (where above test is defined) is as: **getting-started/test/app.test.js**

**import { compareIssueDate } from '../src/controllers/hello.controller';**

If I use import statement, it gives error as: **Cannot use import statement outside a module**

**const compareIssueDate = require("../src/controllers/hello.controller");**

If I use require statement, it gives error as: **Cannot find module '../src/controllers/hello.controller**

How to access above function inside app.test.js. Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Please try changing the tests to TypeScript (i.e. file ends with ‘.ts’)

Comment: Thanks for your fast response.
Changing app.test.js to app.test.ts gives the following error:
Error: No test files found